# How to change tap to click using "defaults write" from command line?

Tags: command-line, preferences, defaults

I want to change the trackpad tap-to-click property from the command line. Graphically, I can do it by clicking System Preferences -> Trackpad -> Tap to Click. How can I do it from  the command line?

I have tried:

```
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad Clicking -int 0
defaults write GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.tapBehavior -int 0
```

but these didn't work (with int as 1 and 0, with reboot). Am I missing some step? I have Macbook 5,1 Snow Leopard.

Comment: How do you know that those are the correct keys for the tap-to-click behavior? Have you diffed the relevant files before and after changing the preference in the system GUI?

Comment: Both lines are instructions from google searches and the upperone is changed when I use gui. I also tried with -bool true/false as Clicking-key is actually boolean. Is there other places what I should tinker with? Like "allow-command-line-access = true"?

Comment: There's no allow-command-line-access setup; `defaults` should work. Have you checked boolean YES/NO or string true/false/yes/no?

Answer (score 7):

Got it to work. The correct format (for me) is:

```
defaults -currentHost write -globalDomain com.apple.mouse.tapBehavior -int 0
```

Change 0 to 1 if you want to enable the tap-to-click. This seems to be really sensitive to which version you are using. The commands in the question have worked for others.

Logout - login is required for this to work.

Alternatively, run

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemAdministration.framework/Resources/activateSettings -u
```

Comment: If you need to logout and login, what do you gain by avoiding Sys Pref GUI?

Comment: Do it for 100 computers/accounts after every upgrade (once per year). Command line automates banal tasks.

Comment: In addition to automation, it's a nice log of one's preferences.

Comment: Tested and works with MacOSX-Catalyst (10.15.7); Too bad this does not mention command to restart Track-pad app and/or driver (something avoiding need to logout/login).

Comment: Adding to this: According to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/414836/130792), you can make `defaults write` take effect without logout-login/restarting with `activateSettings -u`

Answer (score 1):

I had the following in [my `.osx` file](http://mths.be/osx):

```
# Enable tap to click (Trackpad) for this user and for the login screen
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad Clicking -bool true
defaults -currentHost write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.mouse.tapBehavior -int 1
defaults write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.mouse.tapBehavior -int 1
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with Mojave but given this was so long ago, I'm not surprised.

Comment: Try the following solution which worked for me on Mojave: https://osxdaily.com/2014/01/31/turn-on-mac-touch-to-click-command-line/