# How can I enable Trackpad tap-to-click for the login window in OS X 10.8?

Tags: macos, trackpad, multi-touch

In older OS X versions, [this used to work just fine](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20070224105049800):

```
defaults write /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.tapBehavior -int 1
```

It would enable tap to click for built-in MacBook Trackpads for the root user, which would also affect the login screen. There are similar commands to enable it for Bluetooth-based Magic Trackpads as well.

Unfortunately it doesn’t seem to work in OS X 10.8 anymore. Is there some other way of doing this in Mountain Lion?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: And why not down votes and comments on the wrong answers below that haven't been tried / don't actually work?

Answer (score 7):

Turns out you can add this as a function in the Terminal:

`sudo defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad Clicking -int 1`

That worked for me, thanks to these guys - http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1218257

Comment: This worked for me on a MacBook Air running 10.8.4, both with the built in trackpad and a bluetooth Magic Trackpad.

Comment: This worked for me with Retina MacBook Pro on OS X Yosemite (10.10.2) with Magic Trackpad.  Thank you!

Comment: Didn't work on my rMBP 13" with 10.10.2.

Answer (score 6):

I've had mixed results with enabling it for the login screen between my macs.

Here's how I have gotten it to work:

1. Go to System Preferences (as an admin user) -> Users and Groups -> Login Options
2. Click the lock and enter your admin credentials
3. Next to Network Account Server click Edit (or add, what ever comes up if you don't have a server already set up) and then click "Open Directory Utility"
4. Click the lock again and reenter your credentials
5. In the menu bar, click edit and then click "Enable Root User"
6. Set up a password for the user, and then log out of your current user
7. At the login screen, you should have a "Other..." option next to your users. Type in "root" as your username and use the password you set up.
8. Enable tap to click through System Preferences.
9. Log out, and go back into your normal user, and open up Directory Utility again
10. Click on the padlock to authenticate in Directory Utility, and then go to edit on the menu bar, and click "Disable Root User"

## **For security's sake, make sure you disable the root user!**

Now I mentioned at the start I've had mixed results for this. It worked fine on my Mac Mini 2012, but it didn't seem to work on my MacBook Air 2011. The thing that I can think of primarily is that the MacBook Air's trackpad is built in and connected via USB, whereas the Mac Mini's trackpad is bluetooth.

Why does this matter, you ask? Did anyones else notice that the Terminal command that was used to change the system default to having Tap to Click on seems to store the setting in an entry that references *AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad*?

If thats the reason, then that would be why some people report the terminal command works and others say it makes no difference.

I'm going to dig more in this, I wonder if there is a similar *AppleUSBMultitouch.trackpad* entry somewhere...

### Edits:

1. Just confirming, I connected my Bluetooth Trackpad to my MacBook Air (it is surprisingly difficult to remove a trackpad from bluetooth preferences on a desktop mac by the way) and I can Tap to Click on the login screen with the bluetooth trackpad, but not the built in one. *Innerestin'!*
2. Oh, for comparison to your systems, both my Macs are running 10.8.4, have no startup items at all (I like my speedy boot times) and have no third party Kexts

Comment: Tried this, tried the terminal commad with `com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad Clicking 1`, neither worked on my rMBP 13" OSX 10.10.2.

Answer (score 4):

On 10.8 the correct wording seems to be

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad Clicking 1
```

(not sure if the `-int` switch is really needed). This does not turn on click-to-tap immediately and if somebody can tell how to *apply* that default, i'd be a happy little admin :)

Comment: I'd say `-int` is *not* needed, works here just fine without.

Comment: +1. I tested this on my 2014 Macbook Air with OS X Mavericks and it works. Note that `sudo` is needed even if you are using an admin account. (Before I changed the defaults, I opened the terminal from an admin account and typed `sudo defaults read com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad Clicking` and then repeated the same command but without sudo. The former reported 0 while the latter returned 1.) The `-int` in `-int 1` is to specify that 1 is an integer. Apparently the switch can be omitted but it doesn't hurt to include it. One may also replace the part `-int 1` by `-bool true`.

Comment: Anyway, in view of Howard's answer, it seems that one needs to change different domains/keys on different versions of the OS or different models of machines.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried enabling dragging in System Preferences > Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad > Trackpad Options?

(From [How to change tap to click using "defaults write" from command line?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48112))

Comment: Dragging doesn’t seem to have anything to do with this. I also don’t see any reference to this setting in the thread you linked to.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried this myself, but [this might be what you're looking for](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4137099): `sudo defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad Clicking -int 1`

Comment: Just want to point out the following command does not work in 10.8 `sudo defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad Clicking -int 1`

Comment: I found that one [on MacRumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1218257) as well — but it doesn’t seem to work on OS X 10.8 either.

Answer (score -1):

Are you talking about the "Tap to click"? If so you can enable and disable in

System Preferences > Trackpad > Tap to Click

Comment: At least for me it has changed. I'm using Mountain Lion

Comment: Not for me. This only changes the settings for the current user, not the login screen.

Answer (score -2):

System Preferences > Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad > Trackpad Options > check Enable Dragging with/without Draglock.

Comment: What does this have to do with the issue at hand? How can this work?