# El Capitan - Enable Tap-to-click on login screen

Tags: macos, trackpad, click

I want to enable Tap-to-click for my trackpad on the login screen of my MacBook Pro with El Capitan 10.11.6 (15G1004).

I tried everything proposed on [this old question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58461/how-can-i-enable-trackpad-tap-to-click-for-the-login-window-in-os-x-10-8) but nothing has worked.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 3):

I just tried this and it worked on Sierra but should work on older versions too... The internal trackpad uses a different driver (USB) so need to enable a different default

`sudo defaults write com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad Clicking 1`

Answer (score 0):

Type the following in the terminal and reboot device after that.

```
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad Clicking -bool true
defaults -currentHost write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.mouse.tapBehavior -int 1
defaults write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.mouse.tapBehavior -int 1
```

I've tested them on my Macbook Pro 15" 2015 running `10.11.6`

Source: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.macos

[Mathias Bynens](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/4408/mathias-bynens) posted a [similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58461/how-can-i-enable-trackpad-tap-to-click-for-the-login-window-in-os-x-10-8) a few years ago. He wrote the above file on Github.

Comment: I just tested the first on my MBP13" 2010 running 10.11.6 and using user switching to get to the login window do not see tap-to-click working. Does it require a restart or logging out or something like that?

Comment: Sorry, for the missing information. It requires a logout.

Comment: Thank you @varunyellina, but unfortunately it's not working for me. :(

Is there something I can check to figure out where is the problem? Is that command meant to edit any configuration file on the system?

Comment: They did work for me. Just to confirm, I did further testing and they don't seem to be very reliable. I'll update the answer with proper results.

Comment: Neither this is working for me (the updated answer with the Bynens code)... :(

Comment: Hope you rebooted your device.

Comment: Yes, I did twice...
I opened the terminal, logged in as root with `sudo su` and then pasted the 3 commands, then `reboot` from the terminal itself.
The second time I repeated the process but rebooted from the system menu.

Did you typed the commands as root or did you use `sudo`?

Comment: I typed the commands without sudo as a regular user.

Comment: I've just tried without sudo but doesn't work.